# how to implement laravel REST services to use with HTML and Mobile backend

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

I am building a laravel site to use with mobile backend, I have the controllers set up, I am wondering how can I use the same route to return both HTML and JSON, for instance if I do a :

> Post request  to /users/

I would like to create a User, but if form is submitted through HTML I would like to return an HTML page, if it was posted using mobile client I would like to return status in JSON.

Or for instance, I send a:

> ```
> get request to
> /article/1
> ```

I would like to return HTML page for web browser, and JSON for mobile client.

Is this possible or I should create 2 different routes / controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use something like the [Laravel 4 user agent class](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-Agent) to achieve that.

So, like so you said, if mobile, return JSON:

```
if(Agent::isMobile()) {
    //return jsonResponse
} else {
    //return the view
};
```